# open graph tags not being read by Facebook but are in page source

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a problem getting Facebook to recognize my open graph tags.  In looking at the source of the page I see the open graph tags properly but when I go to Facebook's open graph tag debugger, it is not picking up the open graph tags.

Here's what the source looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Run When You - Arte House on Joss &amp; Main</title>
<meta name="description" content="With its' vibrant pastel color scheme and and unique design this wall art sign provides the perfect inspirtation for anytime of the day. Comes complete with ..." />    
<meta name="keywords" content="Vintage-Inspired Wood Plank Wall Art" />        
<meta property="fb:admins" content="32604531" />
<meta property="og:title" content="I love the Run When You in the Arte House event at Joss &amp; Main!" />
<meta property="og:description" content="With its' vibrant pastel color scheme and and unique design this wall art sign provides the perfect inspirtation for anytime of the day. Comes complete with ..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://secure.common.josscdn.com/lf/53/hash/15872/5360609/1/Run+When+You.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Joss &amp; Main" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.jossandmain.com/Run-When-You~QVH1296~E627.html" />
```

Here's what the Facebook's debuger pickes up:

URL: https://www.jossandmain.com/Run-When-You~QVH1296~E627.html

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jossandmain.com%2FRun-When-You%7EQVH1296%7EE627.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Joss &amp; Main</title>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="32604531">
```

I'm banging my head on the wall - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the tags are there? Here's what I see in that URL: [image]

Comment: Hah! Okay, I found the issue thanks to your post. The issue is that as a logged-out user the opengraph tags are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem changed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

to just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Source:
http://www.thesoftgrounds.com