# Facebook Open Graph tags only show in my source code when I'm logged into Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

The website in question: http://www.fedterra.ca

My open graph tags for Facebook (and metadata for Twitter) are set in my source code through the header file in my Wordpress theme:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.fedterra.ca/" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Fed Terra: Nourishing Body and Mind" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Stay fed and nourish your territory. Jaime Brooks at Fed Terra offers body and mind empowerment, meal planning and arompatherapy, and regularly teaches classes to stay healthy and make your own valuable gifts." />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://fedterra.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/facebookcard.jpg" />


<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://fedterra.ca" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Nourishing Body and Mind" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Stay fed and nourish your territory. Jaime Brooks at Fed Terra offers body and mind empowerment, meal planning and arompatherapy, and regularly teaches classes to stay healthy and make your own valuable gifts." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://fedterra.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/facebookcard.jpg" />
```

When I view source in an incognito Chrome window, my saved header OG tags disappear. view-source:http://fedterra.ca/

Unsurprisingly, Facebook is not scraping the tags. Twitter card validator is saying I have not whitelisted them.

It seems this individual had the same quirk, but did not post an answer as to how to get the tags to show up for non-logged in users: [open graph tags not being read by Facebook but are in page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539780/open-graph-tags-not-being-read-by-facebook-but-are-in-page-source)

What I've tried:

- Deactivated any unnecessary plugins
- Changing the header file via FTP
- Adding tags through Yoast plugin

Comment: How exactly are you setting them? Please show your full code which sets these tags.

Comment: Seconding @IgorYavych's suggestion to include the code that sets the tags. This will yield more useful answers, I think.

Comment: Hi Igor, Meghan – just want to confirm what amount of code you were looking for, so I can improve my future asks. Please excuse my cursory understanding for now, but what constitutes the full code which sets the tags? What code beyond the metatags I put in the ask? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Time to shut down my own question.

Turns out the server for this client (and this is my layperson understanding of it) is slow. Very slow. I've never had OG tags take hours or even minutes to propagate, but that's all it was.

After 2 hours of scouring for answers here and setting up a profile to ask, I see they've propagated (I assume) now because the Facebook share card preview is finally scraping and showing my tags.

Here's where to test your share card: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

P.S. Yes I did spell correct aromatherapy.

Comment: Pages are cached pehaps?

Comment: That's an important consideration. I have been testing everything in incognito tabs in Chrome to make it easier to see uncached pages first. I have also been hard refreshing everything. What I'm curious about is: did the Facebook developers page cache the results? But my source code reflected the problem in an uncached page.

Comment: You were getting uncached page, yes, and you were seeing the tags. Question is, were crawlers getting uncached page? And yes, both Twitter and FB cache these tags afaik (can be mistaken though)